# Plotly: ValueError: Invalid element(s) received for the 'steps' property of layout.slider

Tags: python, plotly

I made a simple line graph with matplotlib and now I want to make it with plotly so I can add a slider so I can iterate through years rather than be a static graph, this would be more interactive.

Here is my code so far.

```
df_summed = df_pre_2003.groupby(['year']) ['nAllNeonic'].sum().reset_index()
q=df_summed.year
r=df_summed.nAllNeonic
data = [dict(
        visible = False,
        #line=dict(color='#00CED1', width=6),
        #name = ' = '+str(step),
        x = q,
        y = r
)]
print(data)
#data[0] seems off but not getting an index out of range error so leaving for now
data[0]['visible'] = True
steps=[]
for i in range (0,11,len(q)):
    steps.append(q)   
    step=dict(
        method = 'restyle',  
        args = ['visible', [False] * len(data)],
    )
    step['args'][1][i] = True # Toggle i'th trace to "visible"
    steps.append(step)
sliders=[dict(
    active = 11,
    currentvalue = {"prefix": "Year: "},
    #pad = {"t": 50},
    steps = steps
)]
layout = dict(sliders=sliders)
fig = dict(data=data, layout=layout)
plot(fig, filename='test slider')
```

When I run it I get this error:

> Invalid element(s) received for the 'steps' property of layout.slider

```
Invalid elements include: 
[0     1991
1     1992
2     1993
3     1994
4     1995
5     1996
6     1997
7     1998
8     1999
9     2000
10    2001
11    2002
Name: year, dtype: int64]
```

> The 'steps' property is a tuple of instances of
>       Step that may be specified as:
>         - A list or tuple of instances of plotly.graph_objs.layout.slider.Step
>         - A list or tuple of dicts of string/value properties that
>           will be passed to the Step constructor
>   Supported dict properties: args,execute, label, etc

I do not get why it is telling me that since it is exactly the years I want to step through with the slider. 
When I print the data is gives me this (which is right):

```
[{'visible': False, 'x': 0     1991
1     1992
2     1993
3     1994
4     1995
5     1996
6     1997
7     1998
8     1999
9     2000
10    2001
11    2002
Name: year, dtype: int64, 'y': 0          0.0
1          0.0
2          0.0
3      11207.2
4      82134.0
5     101002.5
6     185898.7
7     166324.4
8     140227.8
9     133949.2
10    143690.4
11    168746.2
Name: nAllNeonic, dtype: float64}]
```

When I print steps is gives me this:

```
[0     1991
1     1992
2     1993
3     1994
4     1995
5     1996
6     1997
7     1998
8     1999
9     2000
10    2001
11    2002
Name: year, dtype: int64, {'method': 'restyle', 'args': ['visible', [True]]}]
```

It seems like it should work but I am getting that error. Any insight would be great. Thanks!
Also, as a side note I am following this example. https://plot.ly/python/sliders/